# order a list with dictionaries on python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have this:

```py
def removeFromFront(node, front):
    tmpFront = front
    flagFound = False
    for i in range(len(tmpFront)):
        for j in (range(len(tmpFront[i]) - 3)):
            if tmpFront[i][j] == node[j]:
                flagFound = True
            else:
               flagFound = False
               break
        if (flagFound):
            if (tmpFront[i][5]['realCost'] + tmpFront[i][6]['heuristicEstimation']) > (node[5]['realCost'] + node[6]['heuristicEstimation']):
                        tmpFront.pop(i)
                        tmpFront.insert(i, node)
        else:
            tmpFront.append(node)
        if (len(tmpFront) > 1): 
            #sorted(tmpFront, key=lambda k: k['totalCost'], reverse = False)
            tmpFront.sort(key=operator.itemgetter('totalCost'))
        foundFlag = False
    
    if (len(tmpFront) == 0):
        tmpFront.append(node)
    return tmpFront
```

and front is like this:
Front:

```
[[3, ['E', 'NO'], ['P1', 'NO'], ['P2', 'NO'], ['P3', 'NO'], {'realCost': 0}, {'heuristicEstimation': 15},{'totalCost': 29}]]
[[3, ['P1', 'NO'], ['E', 'Yes'], ['P2', 'NO'], ['P3', 'NO'], {'realCost': 1}, {'heuristicEstimation': 15},{'totalCost': 29}], [3, ['P3', 'NO'], ['P1', 'NO'], ['P2', 'Yes'], ['E', 'NO'], {'realCost': 1}, {'heuristicEstimation': 28},{'totalCost': 29}]]
```

I get the following:

```
search_algorithm_front_queue.py", line 383, in removeFromFront
    tmpFront.sort(key=operator.itemgetter('totalCost'))
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

The exception is because you are using `itemgetter` with wrong argument type: `str`.
As the exception says.

If you want to sort by the value of `totalCost` and it is always the 8th item, I would go with:

Sort with `key= lambda x: x[7]['totalCost']`